# Is there a way to get the outer controller name from directive in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to AngularJS...Here is the quesiton:

for example:

#### HTML

```
<div ng-controller='DemoController'>
  <div my-directive></div>
</div>
```

#### JavaScript

```
app.directive('myDirective', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
      //I want to get the outer controller name (in this case 'DemoController') here when using this directive
      // var controller_name = ?
    }
  };
});
```

How can I get the outer controller name ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Why do you need the string name of the Controller inside the directive? There probably is a better way to do what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @musically_ut I want to get the outer div which has the attribute 'ng-controller' whose value is the controller name and do some DOM manipulation.Just pass a value to the scope like this $scope.controller_name='DemoController' maybe a easier way...But thus I can not get the controller name automatically and I must specify the value manually...

Comment: That doesn't quite explain the _why_ part, but if you _absolutely_ **really** _really_ want to do it via only the templates, then include `jQuery` and use `$element.closest('[ng-controller'])`: http://plnkr.co/edit/yDrMUbk9vf5Bxy7VLkTs?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just pass whatever you want to your directive, using its attributes. See the [guide about directives](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive). In your case it's fine to do:

HTML

```
<div ng-controller='DemoController'>
  <div my-directive="DemoController"></div>
</div>
```

JS

```
app.directive('myDirective', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
      var controller_name = attrs.myDirective;
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Your solution can work, but I used to think the directive can be aware of where itself lives in, something like: controller_name = scope.controller_name ...

Comment: Yes, it's possible to set `controller_name` variable on the scope in your controller or any other value for that matter. However I don't think you can get the controller name just from angular's configuration.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller='DemoController'>
  <div my-directive></div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
app.directive('myDirective', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller_name){
      //I want to get the outer controller name (in this case 'DemoController') here when using this directive
      console.log(controller_name);//using this you can get your current controller name
    }
  };
});
```